# Short story where an astronaut is sent into space, and then a few years later is found by a significantly more advanced ship, also from Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can anyone tell me the name of a science fiction short story where a spaceship is sent out on an exploration mission from Earth. And then after a few years, the progress of technology is such that humanity spreads to local space and picks up the forgotten original spacecraft as a relic? With the lone pilot waking up to a world far advanced

It's an older one, definitely pre-2000. I remember reading it in a short anthology of sci-fi stories I found on the shelves of a used book store as a kid, so I can't remember a specific title or author. Please it's driving me crazy!

The overall message of the story was to illustrate how the progression of technology can outpace previous efforts, suggesting it's better to wait until technology is more advanced, and asking the question how long should we really wait.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightspeedLeapfrog

Comment: Probably "Far Centaurus" by A. E. van Vogt which you can read here: https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v32n05_1944-01_frankenscan/page/n67/mode/1up

Comment: Note that "Far Centarus" is by far the best fit on the *Lightspeed Leapfrog* page, and a good candidate for the answer.

Comment: "Far Centaurus" is the most famous story on that theme but it's not a lone pilot and they are not intercepted in midspace., so maybe it's one of the copycats.

Comment: @user14111 You are a godsend, that is exactly the one I was thinking of. It seems time has corroded my memory of the details, but you have no idea the relief of finding this. Thank you!

Comment: That is also a scan of the exact version I picked up in that musty old book store oh so long ago.

Comment: @InkedZoo You're welcome!

Comment: @user14111 Ah, I had not seen that.  My apologies.